# SQL How to reuse the case statement in select and having clause?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, having-clause

I'm trying to make my query a little less complex and better performance(faster). Currently it takes really long as the data is over 10million records!

I thought i can do it by not repeating the case statement in select and having clause(they are same). 
I had another repeated statement in select and having clause(fc.Activity_Amount) which I removed by adding a left join(*). But i dont know how to get rid of case statemnt being used twice?

I have a couple more joins and related conditions in where clause that i have removed here. mentioning this to state that the query is really complex and takes really long to execute! 1 million records take nearing 20 mins.

```
Select (Case When Aca2.Cycle_Activity_Amount Is Null Then 0 Else Aca2.Cycle_Activity_Amount End +
        Case When Aa.Activity_Amount Is Null Then 0 Else Aa.Activity_Amount End) As "TF",  
       Fc.Activity_Amount As Cap
From Account_Cycle_Activity Aca   
  Join school Ca On Aca.Account_Id = Ca.Account_Id 
  left join ( 
    SELECT ACCOUNT_ID, ACTIVITY_AMOUNT 
    FROM ACCOUNT_ACTIVITY 
    WHERE ACTIVITY_TYPE_CODE = '112' 
      and POINT_IN_TIME_CODE = 'YR1' 
  ) Aa On Aca.Account_Id = Aa.Account_Id
  Left Join (
    Select Account_Id, Cycle_Activity_Amount, Cycle_Ctr  
    From Account_Cycle_Activity 
    Where Activity_Type_Code = '112' 
      And Activity_Group_Code = '2CY'
  ) Aca2 On Aca.Account_Id = Aca2.Account_Id And Aca2.Cycle_Ctr=Ca.Cycle_Ctr

  Left Join ( 
     Select Activity_Amount, Account_Id 
     From Account_Activity 
     Where Activity_Type_Code = '113' And Point_In_Time_Code = 'YR1'
  ) Fc On Aca.Account_Id = Fc.Account_Id**

Where  Aca.Cycle_Ctr=Ca.Cycle_Ctr 
Group By  Aca2.Cycle_Activity_Amount,Aa.Activity_Amount,fc.Activity_Amount
Having (Case When Aca2.Cycle_Activity_Amount Is Null Then 0 Else Aca2.Cycle_Activity_Amount End + 
        Case When Aa.Activity_Amount Is Null Then 0 Else Aa.Activity_Amount End) >  fc.ACTIVITY_AMOUNT;
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Some databases allow column aliases in the having clause.

Comment: You can use `COALESCE()` instead of those `CASE` statements. But there is probably more to your performance problem than just that.

Comment: "select ... from (select ....) having..."

Comment: Gordon I'm using Oracle11g and it doesnt allow me to use select aliases in having clause

Comment: The query displayed is using `GROUP BY`, but no aggregations, so it is unclear why you are using the `HAVING` clause. I suspect you do need aggregations. It is unlikely that repetition of the case expression is adding measurably to your query. The case expression itself could definitely be replaced with `NVL(Aca2.Cycle_Activity_Amount,0) + NVL(Aa.Activity_Amount,0)` OR use `COALESCE()` if preferred. **I suggest you get an explain plan** and add the output of it to your question (as text, not an image).